# Comparing the results of two sub-queries

Tags: t-sql, subquery

I need to import data from a database. The contacts are linked to companies in two ways : *via* contact informations, or *via* an "activity". I need to get some lists.

The list of contacts without companies is easy enough :

```
where idcontact not in (select idcontact from tb_contact_soc where idcontact is not null)
and idcontact not in (select idcontact from tb_activite_soc_contact where idcontact is not null)
```

The list of contacts with multiple companies is more tricky.
idcontact is the id of the contact ; ident is the id of the company.
Tb_contact_soc is the table that links via contact infos [idcontact, ident, telephone, fax] ; tb_activite_soc_contact is the table that links via activities [idcontact,ident,activityCode].

```
where
(
    -- contacts linked via their contact informations
    idcontact in (
        select idcontact
        from tb_contact_soc
        where idcontact is not null and ident is not null
        group by idcontact
        having count(*) > 1
    )
    -- contacts linked via an activity
    or idcontact in (
        select idcontact
        from tb_activite_soc_contact
        where idcontact is not null and ident is not null
        group by idcontact
        having count(*) > 1
    )
) and (
    -- here goes the snipplet I can't figure out
)
```

In the last "and", I need to say something like "where, for this contact, at least one of the companies from the tb_contact_soc table is not found in the companies from the tb_activite_soc_contact table". But I can't figure it out.

I only need to get it once, so our customer can validate the data before we launch the import, so it can be a bit convulted (not too much, thanks ;) )

Comment: Is there a company identifier in the tables tb_contact_soc table and tb_activite_soc_contact?

Comment: Yes. I have updated my question to add a simili-schema : Tb_contact_soc [idcontact, ident, telephone, fax] ; tb_activite_soc_contact [idcontact,ident,activityCode].

Comment: Have posted an answer.. pls chk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and clause(I assume you are using SQL 2005 or higher):

```
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT ident
        FROM tb_contact_soc a
     WHERE a.idcontact = <PARENT_QUERY_TABLE_ALIAS>.idcontact
       AND a.ident IS NOT NULL
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ident         
        FROM tb_activite_soc_contact a
     WHERE a.idcontact = <PARENT_QUERY_TABLE_ALIAS>.idcontact
       AND ident IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: It gives me a different number of results from what I have found doing c# code... (sql : 30 contacts ; c# : 64) but I don't know if it's the sql or the c# code that is wrong. Thanks anyway, at the very least I will have discovered a sql function :)